# ADO pipeline System Access Token permissions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a script that interacts with Azure DevOps projects using the ADO API. I recently changed from using a Personal Access Token (PAT) to a System Access Token.

It works fine in certain projects but in others I'm getting an error when trying to create a new branch:

> Unable to create branch "whatever" [updateStatus: createBranchPermissionRequired]

I accessed the "Security" tab in the "Repositories" settings and checked that "Project Collection Build Service" has the "Create branch" permission allowed. Still it fails.

I'm wondering if that's the right user.

Is there a way to get the name of the user I should update from the access token?

Is there something else I should check/try?